# $A = (a_{ij})$ in the matrix definition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I have the following matrix definition

> An m × n (read “m by n”) matrix A over a set S is a rectangular array
> of elements of S arranged into m rows and n columns: (an mn matrix
> shown)
>
> We write $A = (a_{ij})$.

What is the meaning of $A = (a_{ij})$? $a_{ij}$ is an elements in the matrix, what's the point it writing this equality?

Comment: You can read $(a_{ij})$ here as a shorthand for the matrix $(a_{ij})_{\substack{i=1,\dots,m\\j=1,\dots,n}}$, that is, the $m\times n$ matrix whose entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column is $a_{ij}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some times you want to talk about the matrix as a whole. Then you use $A$. Some times you want to talk about the elements. Then you use $a_{ij}$. The point of writing the equality is to formally establish that they are, ultimately, just two different notations for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

$(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$
This is how we write double sequences. And a matrix is a finite  double sequence. So matrix $A$ is written as
$$A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n}$$
But when from the context, size of the matrix is clear then mostly we omit the suffix and simply we write
$$A=(a_{ij})$$

Answer (score 0):

It means: we call the matrix $A$ and the element in the $i$th row and $j$th column $a_{ij}$. Furthermore, we sometimes don't want to introduce a new symbol for the matrix formed by some elements $a_{ij}$. Then, we simply write $(a_{ij})$ in the implicit understanding that this denotes the matrix formed by the different $a_{ij}$ and not a specific $a_{ij}$ enclosed by normal brackets.

Furthermore it means: we will do the same for every matrix. Thus, from now on whenever some upper case letter denotes a matrix, we will denote by a corresponding lower case letter with two indices the elements of the matrix.

Comment: I disagree with that last  paragraph. Unless explicitly stated, I understand "We write $A=(a_{ij})$ as a definition of **only** the values $a_{ij}$, not of any other potential values $b_{ij}$ if some matrix $B$ exists.

Comment: @5xum why? I often see something along the line of "let $I=(\delta_{ij})$, with $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ otherwise".

Comment: What you wrote has nothing to do with what I am saying. My point is that if the author writes "We write $A=(a_{ij})$", that does **not** mean that, if somewhere else in the text, a variable $b_{ij}$ appears, then $b_{ij}$ is an element of matrix $B$. Your final paragraph implies exactly that.

Comment: @5xum : OK, I now got what you meant. I think, context might be important here. So, if under some formula in the middle of a paper I read "... with $A=(a_{ij})$", I agree with you. However, when I read "We write [..]", as in the original question, than I interpret whatever follows as a notation convention which generalizes. Thus, in this case, the equal sign means that the two notations are equivalent _in general_. This makes the more sense since $A$ clearly stands here as a placeholder for "any matrix".

Answer (score 0):

By

> We write $A=(a_{ij})$

the author means to say the following:

> If at any point from here on, we write $a_{ij}$, we are referring to the value in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of matrix $A$.

In other words, a little counterintuitively, the expression $A=(a_{ij})$ is not actually defininig the value $A$, but rather the values $a_{ij}$ for $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$.